# CRC result with boost::crc_32_type is not same as java.util.zip.CRC32

Tags: java, c++

I want to generate crc code of a string in my c++ code using boost::crc_32_type then later regenerate it in java using (java.util.zip.CRC32) but the result is not the same. Anyone can help?

Comment: Give example of usage boost::crc32.

Comment: Give both. Show your code. They both use the same polynomial and other parameters so they should give the same result.

Comment: You say "string" - if any data going into the checksum on the Java side actually _is_ a string at some point, make sure that you're converting it to `byte[]` correctly before updating `CRC32`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So. Results are equal.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
                String s = new String("123456789");
                java.util.zip.CRC32 crc32 = new java.util.zip.CRC32();
                crc32.update(s.getBytes());
                System.out.println(crc32.getValue());
        }
}
```

> 3421780262

http://ideone.com/Q1GTB

```
#include <boost/crc.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   const std::string str = "123456789";
   boost::crc_32_type crc32;
   crc32 = std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), crc32);
   std::cout << crc32() << std::endl;
}
```

> 3421780262

http://liveworkspace.org/code/0a5c4f1eaa920bd0161f7d37fa809aa3

Comment: Actually instead of this for_each I had used process_bytes() and later checksum() functions of boost so the result was different from the one with Java.

Comment: @user562549, is there any difference between for_each and process_bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same CRC algorithm on the same bits in order for the results to reliably be the same. You can implement your own CRC algorithm in both Java and C++, or you can implement one CRC library's algorithm in the other language.

Edit: I just want to emphasize that your *bits* need to be the same. It is very possible your C++ string has a different encoding and/or character size than your Java String.